# dblclick event on tr doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I ve got a html page with only a table with two rows and i want to add an dobleclick event via jQuery. My problem is that this code don´t run, but if i use javascript console of chrome and type manually the code, code runs.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('tr').dblclick(function(){
alert('Row dblclicked');
});
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you try reproduce your problem on a pastebin, like http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I set the fiddle to use jquery instead of mootools and added a border for clarity, and your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/SQzt6/1/ - your problem is likely somewhere else... have you included jquery properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you are not ending your parentheses for `$(document).ready()`

You are missing `);` right at the end of your script.

Try changing your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('tr').dblclick(function(){
alert('Row dblclicked');
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/SQzt6/4/

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LUNuq/

Answer (score 0):

You just have a syntaxt problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('tr').dblclick(function(){
    alert('Row dblclicked');
  });
}​);​
```

and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/bouillard/xGgFx/